# disable post request from outside of website with session (php security)

Tags: php, security

i want disable post request that sent from another url or software (CSRF attacks)
and notice that : ( i don't want set csrf token **input** for my forms )

is accepted if i set csrf token in **session** after users login  ?
thanks

Comment: what's the reason not to use CSRF tokens in the forms? Nothing beats it

Comment: @ClaudioPinto because i have a lot form without this !!

Comment: Well, then you'll have an insecure system. Doing that kind of refactoring is not hard, you can do 100 forms in an hour or so, less if you use some kind of framework and an MVC approach. CSRF are temporary tokens, and that is the beauty of it

Comment: @ClaudioPinto but if i write < if (isset($_SESSION['...'])) > in top of my pages (in my config file) ... it Will be safe . Will not?

Comment: not really https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack, although CSRF can be stored in sessions their temporary and generated for that unique request expiring immediately after that. What you suggest is just a session variable which is just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid CRSF, you don't have any good options.  The `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable is often set and usually corresponds to the website the request came from, so you could use it to block *some* foreign requests. However like all data coming from the browser, you cannot trust it without verification so it should not be considered secure. [The docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and
>   some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In
>   short, it cannot really be trusted.

CSRF checking is the best option to prevent foreign domains from making requests. You don't have to include it as an input on your forms if you don't want to; you can use cookies and headers instead:

**1.** When the user logs in, use PHP's `setcookie` to store a token in cookies. Store a matching token in the user session, along with an expiration date

```
$token = '...'; //<- look up how to generate a good random token
$expire = time()+1800; //expire in 30 minutes
setcookie("XSRF-TOKEN", $token, $expire);  /* expire in 1 hour */
$_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'] = ['token'=>$token, 'exp'=>$expire];
```

**2.** When your site makes a request, use Javascript to read the token from `document.cookie` and set the header below with the exact same value:

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN: 43b7acd76d6....
```

If you're worried about having to update a big website, this is your best bet. You can instruct the browser to run a Javascript function whenever it's about to make an HTTP request. This function could read the cookie and set the header. Many frameworks will do this for you, but for vanilla JS, look at [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers).

**3.** Whenever your PHP script receives a request, first look for the value of this header, then compare it to what you saved in the user session. Remember to check for expiration!

```
$request_token = apache_request_headers()['X-XSRF-TOKEN']? : null;
$session_token = $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'];
if($request_token===null) die('Token is missing');
if($session_token['exp'] < time()) die('Token has expired');
if($session_token['token']!==$request_token) die('Token is invalid');
//safe to continue. Repeat step 1 to set a fresh token
```

Only the domain that can read the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie will know what value to set in the header.  Since browsers do not allow one domain to read cookies from another, this mechanism will protect you from requests of bad origin. And it keeps the csrf bits out of your forms as you asked.

Comment: thanks . but is it safe from XSS attacks somethings like this : <SCRIPT>alert(document.cookie);</SCRIPT> for hackers ?

Comment: No. `XSS` is a different class of attack, and a completely different topic from what you asked about.  "*disable post requests from foreign websites and apps*" is about `CSRF`.  Putting tokens in your forms will not protect you from `XSS` either.

Comment: I meant i want disable access cookie in javascript for xss . but you said (When your site makes a request, use Javascript to read the token from document.cookie and set the header below with the exact same value:) excuse me if i junior @BeetleJuice

Comment: For the CSRF scheme above to work, Javascript must be able to read the cookie.  If you don't want csrf in your forms and you don't want JS to see the token, you cannot protect yourself from CSRF.  Keeping your site safe from `XSS` is a separate issue.  To learn how to deal with it, read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/